# How i can use xuggler to capture audio and video?

Tags: audio, video, record, xuggler

Any good code example to capture audio and video using xuggler on a local disc. Or using xuggler i can combine audio.flv file and video.flv file to a single audiovideo.flv file. Please some one help to resolve this problem. Thanks